# Can't execute from /usr/local/bin/ symlink

Tags: linux, path, symlink

I've recently had to compile a program (Riak) from source since they don't have a repo available for Ubuntu 16.04 yet.

I've compiled the program and copied it to /opt/riak where it works fine.

Since this program requires sudo privileges, I've decided to symlink /opt/riak/bin/riak to /usr/local/bin/riak instead of adding the variable to the path via a profile.d file (because in order to work with sudo I'd have to remove env_reset from /etc/sudoers which I rather not do).

The error I get is the following:
/usr/local/bin/riak: 8: .: Can't open /usr/local/bin/../lib/env.sh

Shouldn't the symlink execute the file from the original's working directory? Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is almost self explanatory. Apparently the `riak` executable is trying to find a file called `env.sh` using a path relative to its own, namely `../lib/env.sh`. Originally, this would resolve to the following path: `/opt/riak/bin/../lib/env.sh`, which is the same as `/opt/riak/lib/env.sh`. But now is trying to find the file at `/usr/local/bin/../lib/env.sh` which is the same as `/usr/local/lib/env.sh` and obviously the file is not there.

You have the following options (in order of preference):

1. Leave the program in `/opt` and invoke it from there
2. Leave the program in `/opt` and create a small wrapper shell script in `/usr/local/bin` that calls the original executable (see at the end of this post).
3. Recompile the program passing the right parameters to its `configure` script (e.g. `--prefix=/usr/local`) so that it works from `/usr/local`.

I would recommend against option 3; I prefer to let the `/usr` directory be managed by the distos package manager. If I have to compile something myself, I prefer to put it in a dedicated directory bellow `/opt`. This way, if I want to remove it later on, I can just delete that directory.

Example wrapper script for option 2:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /opt/riak/bin/riak "$@"
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm going with option 2 as it's basically the closest thing to what I wanted to accomplish. I understood the error, I just had no idea how to fix it!